# TDD and the use of Views in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Even after implementing the *Repository pattern* to abstract the data access layer (Eloquent ORM), when you do something like:

```
$students = StudentRepository::all();
return view('students.index', ['students' => $students]);
```

You end up sending either an `\Eloquent\Model` subclass or an `Eloquent\Collection` to the **view**.

This means that if your view attempts to do *lazy-loading* and you run tests cases on a CI server, it's gonna crash due the lack of a database connection.

This problem leads to the following solutions:

1. You mock directly `Eloquent` subclasses in your tests, so that when it attempts to lazy load, you can set the returned value
2. You implement interfaces for each model and bind them using laravel's **IoC**.

The disadvantages for this 2 options would be:

**For option 1:** If you end up mocking Eloquent on your tests, then what's the point of implementing repository pattern (which seems to be very popular due to the "flexibility" if you have to change from Eloquent to a different ORM), since you're gonna have to re-write your tests too.

**For option 2:** If you write interfaces for every `Eloquent\Model`, the only thing you'd have to do is write extra code for setters and getters.

If this far I'm still on the right path, **option 2 would be the best choice** **but there's absolutely not a single thread or info regarding abstracting `Eloquent\Model` into `interfaces`** to mock calls made by the view that are either `lazy-loaded` or just `properties`.

So why is this? Am I not seeing something? maybe tests are supposed to exit before rendering the view (and `$this->assertViewHas($variable)` is pointless)? maybe there's a way to ignore crashes when it occurs in the view? maybe people only unit test JSON API controllers?

Comment: Our tests run migrations/seeds on an in-memory SQLite database, so you can use full model functionality.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution for integration tests. Is this more recommended than just running unit tests?

Comment: I prefer it as it lets us test actual functionality, not mocked-up versions of it. We just do a `Artisan::call('migrate');` in the base `TestCase` class's `setup()` function and use `'database' => ':memory:'` in the SQLite database config.

Comment: Do you guys implement repository pattern?

Comment: One of our devs is starting to use it, but I haven't played personally. I don't think this technique should be affected by its implementation.

Comment: So basically you test the complete cycle itself, for example, you put an array on Input::replace() then call PUT on your resource and test if status is 200 ?

Comment: Yes, our tests involve the complete creation of Eloquent models. Helps us ensure our migrations etc. are all functional too.

Comment: If you are implementing the repository pattern, you shouldn't need to code your models to an interface, just your repositories.  Then you'd inject those implementations into your controllers via automatic dependency injection and service providers and mock them in your tests.  I'd also suggest using `->toArray()` on all your repository methods where possible because it's easier to make your mocks return arrays than collections/models when testing.

Comment: @user3158900 I did the repository via automatic dependency, the issue is on the View, the controller is fine...

Comment: I'd go for opt1, how many times have you switched from Eloquent to something else before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a bird? Is it a plane? No, it's the rarely used and barely documented Laravel Fluent class to the rescue!

The Fluent class allows you to emulate all of the functionality of a model or other abstract class with attributes, but without carrying around the weight or dependencies of the model class itself. It's very similar to classes that you might build as entity classes when you are using a data mapper ORM like Doctrine instead of Laravel's Eloquent.

A Fluent object can be built by providing an array of attributes as key=>value pairs like this:

```
$myobject = new Fluent(['id' => 666]);
```

You can access the attributes using magic setters and getters just like a model object:

```
$myobject->id = 999;
$myId = $myobject->id;
```

and furthermore, because the Laravel Model class is Arrayable and has a toArray() function you can use these methods to create your Fluent object.

```
$myobject = new Fluent($mydatamodel->toArray());
```

By using fluent in your Repository classes you can remove the dependency on the Laravel model objects from your views but still have the convenience of the magic setters and getters.  Of course there's a little more jiggery-pokery in taking the results of MyModel::all() and turning that into an array of Fluents but in my case I wrote a trait to do that and attached it to my models.  I also added a trait to populate a model directly from a Fluent but that's an exercise left to the reader.

http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Support/Fluent.html